# Close the cmd after running program?

Tags: windows, cmd

I know next to nothing about the command prompt, and even less about windows 10, so I apologize if this isn't incredibly clear. I have an issue with Windows 10 permissions allowing a program to be run on standard users desktops. The way to fix this is to run the program "As Administrator" but I don't want the client to have to right click and have an admin come over every time this needs to be run. So after much googling (and I apologize I can't seem to find the website I picked this from), I found this line of code.

```
runas /user:admin_username /savecred "cmd /c \"C:\Users\Files\project.exe\""
```

and this is great! Circumvents the issue I was having (not 100% why though) and the user has to put in a password exactly once.

My problem is that this opens a second command prompt and it doesn't go away. I have tried to remove the `/c` part but that just opens a new prompt and doesn't execute my project.exe. Removing the `"cmd /c"` part doesn't work at all, saying "740: The requested ooperation requires elevation." which was the original error I was trying to avoid. I'm not sure how much it matters, but this command will then go into a shortcut so the user just has to double click an icon and then this will be executed.

So my question, how can I get this to open a second prompt, execute my `.exe` and then close the newly opened prompt?

*EDIT*: I managed to find the [article](http://www.tenforums.com/user-accounts-family-safety/30133-updated-1511-740-requested-operation-requires-elevation.html) I mentioned prior, AndreyT  on   24 Nov 2015 is where I stole/borrowed the code from.

Comment: just stating the obvious (hopefully) - but this is highly insecure and opens up  whoever has access to the stored credentials to execute any arbitrary command as administrator; be careful

Comment: @MikeDinescu Hello and thank you for your concern, I am aware of the security problem. But you're right it is worth stating as I might not be the only person looking at this response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Start command:

```dos
RunAs /User:admin_username /SaveCred "Cmd /C Start \"\" \"C:\Users\Files\project.exe\""
```

Comment: that seems to have done it! I appreciate the timely answer. 1 small further question, the start up time took much longer than usual when the second prompt was instantly closed. Do you know why that might be?